# Flutter webapp slow on startup

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

*I'm new to flutter web, I just created a sample portfolio site in a flutter. It came well but when I build the app it takes 10 seconds delay to startup even I hosted it to a server it takes some time to render. can anyone say why it is happening?*

FLUTTER DOCTOR

> venkat@venkat--linux:~/karthikha_photography$ flutter doctor Doctor
> summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓] Flutter
> (Channel master, 2.1.0-11.0.pre.145, on Linux, locale en_GB.UTF-8) [✓]
> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
> 30.0.3) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1) [✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

gitrepo https://github.com/venki1410/karthikha_photography
**only for mobile devices**
Site url https://incommunicable-volu.000webhostapp.com/#/